# How to override javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, express, global-variables, local-variables

I am working on an Express.io mini project and I am stuck on this variable override problem.

Here is my code:

```
get_time_offset = function(timezone_id){
   Timezone.findById(timezone_id, function(err, doc){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(doc.offset);
        }
   });
}
```

This code block can display the doc.offset's value through the console.log without any problem and I would like to make the doc.offset be available outside the Timezone Object. Here's what I have come up so far:

```
get_time_offset = function(timezone_id){
    var offset;
    Timezone.findById(timezone_id, function(err, doc){
       if(err) {
            console.log(err);
       } else {
          offset = doc.offset;
       }
    });
    console.log(offset);
}
```

It says 'offset is undefined' and I can't seem to find any other way of solving this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking either change your initial declaration to...

```
var offset = {};
```

...or, your console.log is executing before your function has finished. Simple check by adding a log inside the function...

```
    } else {
      offset = doc.offset;
      console.log('from inside ... ', offset);
    }
   });
  }
console.log('from outside ... ', offset);
```

... and see if 'outside' fires first.

EDIT:

If 'from outside' is running first, have your follow-up code called by the initial function.

```
get_time_offset = function(timezone_id){
  var offset;

  function processResult(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }

  Timezone.findById(timezone_id, function(err, doc){
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      offset = doc.offset;
    }
    processResult(offset);
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried your second suggestion. and here's what I got from my terminal:

from outside undefined
from inside 8

Comment: Did 'from outside' show up first? If so, then your 'outside' console log is undefined because the variable actually has not been set yet by the function. It's a timing thing.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your suggested code and it indeed echoed out my Timezone's offset in my console, but the processResult(offset) function is still executing inside the Timzone Object. 

The reason I want it out of the Timezone object is to make the get_time_offset() function have the value of doc.offset by doing a return offset; outside of Timezone Object.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make offset available inside the function you can pass it as a parameter here is demo http://thomasdavis.github.io/tutorial/anonymous-functions.html

```
var scope = {offset : 10};
get_time_offset = function(timezone_id){
    Timezone.findById(timezone_id, function(err, doc, scope){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            scope.offset = doc.offset;
        }
    });
}
console.log(scope.offset);
```

sorry edited: i made a mistake in the example offset must be an object for it to be passed by reference and modified, heres a fiddle i hacked together of it http://jsfiddle.net/VLbVw/4/

Comment: Thank you! I tried making the scope object and passed it as a parameter inside the anonymous function (as you suggested) and I got a "Cannot set property 'offset' of undefined" error.

Comment: Ah probably because that callback def isnt getting scope from findById (my bad!). try without the scope as a parameter to findById's callback. instead just pass it to get_time_offset! this should work!! >.< i updated the fiddle to more closely represent your problem http://jsfiddle.net/VLbVw/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get_time_offset = function(timezone_id, callback){

    Timezone.findById(timezone_id, function(err, doc){
       if(err) {
            console.log(err);
    callback(false);
       } else {
         callback(doc.offset);
       }
    });

};

get_time_offset(5, function(offset){
   console.log(offset)
});
```